# Re: Requests for Code Outsourcing

Tags: support, bounty, code

I agree that Stack Overflow is not a code outsourcing site. But, is it permissible to ask for code in exchange for bounty? The respondent would receive compensation in the form of rewarded reputation points for the outsourcing service. That would seem to me to be a fair exchange.

Edit: Seems moot, at this point, but the prospective bounty question was whether to use var or a constant - probably 2 lines of demo code.

Comment: Also worth noting, if I saw an ad for a developer for a project, and the payment was SO rep instead of cash, I'd turn that down in a heartbeat. SO users are volunteers. If you want to outsource code, pay cash for someone to do it, don't try to pay rep on SO.

Comment: Good idea. I am going to start an outsourcing business that pays its workforce with other intangibles such as items in online games and Facebook pokes.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207757/will-work-for-rep-closing-bounty-questions

Answer (score -5, accepted):

As pointed out, reputation points are nearly worthless. But, they're probably worth more than any answer one would give on SO. Anyway, there are better sites that can actually answer questions. So, in conclusion, it's not even worth the bother.

Comment: And, the better sites don't beg for cash.

Answer (score 10):

No, it is not permissible. Bounties are intended to be used for bringing more attention to a question.

[What is a bounty? How can I start one?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

Your question of course still has to be a valid question, and it's likely that such a request included in the question itself will be removed quickly as it would be considered "fluff", or unrelated to the question.

Comment: Definition of bounty: a monetary gift or reward. In this case, bounty would mean points, rather than cash.

Comment: Note however that it's unlikely any action will be taken against you for doing this, other than receiving downvotes (which could lead to rate limiting on your ability to ask questions)

Comment: @Jim In the context of SO, a bounty is a reward/incentive for answering a question. The question still needs to fit all of the criteria for being a suitable one on the site, and a request to do work for you simply isn't a suitable question.

Answer (score 1):

The point of Stack Overflow is twofold-

First, to solve your immediate **question**, and secondly to help others.

While awarding reputation to a user for helping you out with code outsourcing may seem like a good idea at first glance, it is not very useful to others. Really, it just decreases the signal-to noise ratio here for people looking for genuine **answers**.

So no, it is not permissible. Other sites exist for this that are more appropriate. (And pay in cash.)

Comment: Good point. The signal-to-noise ratio on SO is loud & annoying enough.